# NMap for getting machines connected to a network switch

Tags: nmap

I am currently exploring Nmap for its capabilities. Can anyone tell how can Nmap be used to query the machines connected to a network switch?

Comment: That really depends on what data you're looking to gather. You don't need nmap to do a ping sweep and look at your arp table.

Answer (score 2):

Nmap is not the right tool for that.
"Machines connected to a network switch" is a layer 2 question.
Nmap is a layer 3 tool.